# Maintain last Run dialog items through reboot

Tags: windows-xp

How do I prevent my computer from clearing the Run box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) everytime I reboot?

For example, if I enter in the box "Msconfig" or "Regedit", it works as long as my computer is on. Once rebooted, all entries are gone.

I'm using Windows XP Pro 32-bit, Service Pack 3, AMD processor.

Answer (score 1):

From http://windowsxp.mvps.org/runmru.htm:

> If you're using a third-party system maintenance program like System Mechanic or Fresh UI, disable the corresponding options in that utility which clears the RUN history. Note that some versions of Zone Alarm has a Cache cleaner facility under Privacy settings.
>
> Another possibility is that the ClearRecentDocsOnExit registry value is set to 1 in the following registry key:
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows\ CurrentVersion \ Policies \ Explorer`